# The Atom Riddles #4

Tags: riddle

[Link to other riddles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A56715+title%3A%22The+Atom+Riddles%22)

**Rules**:

- You are trapped in a room by a mad scientist.
- There are clues in each sentence. You have to find the correct atomic element that matches the clues.

> The first sixth of me has the most water 
> Half of me is a common vehicle

> What am I?

Comment: Please don't add meta-commentary to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are:

> Carbon

The first sixth of me has the most water

> The first sixth of the word Carbon is the letter 'C', which is a homophone to 'Sea' a large body of water.

Half of me is a common vehicle

> The first half of the word 'Carbon' is 'Car' - quite the common vehicle.

Comment: Yes it is correct!